# I inherit a list(of string) and want to reduce the instance itself, how?

Tags: vb.net, list, inheritance

I've created a class with inheritance like so:

```
    Public Class PerformanceHistoryLog
       Inherits List(Of String)

           Public Sub ReduceValueCollection(Steps As Integer)
                Dim NewValues as New List(Of String)
                NewValues.Add(First.Value)

                ' copy the new list to the current instance;
                Me = NewValues
           End Sub
     End Class
```

But this part doesn't work;

```
me = NewValues
```

With the error message;

```
BC30068 Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.
```

I've also tried with MyBase etc. Ofcource I can clear the current instance, and copy the values one by one, but what's the best way to go with this? (HansP? ;)

Comment: You can't assign to `Me`.  How would that make sense?  `Me` is the current object so how could the current object take another object and make itself that?  What you need to do is `Clear` the current instance and then `AddRange` to populate the current instance with all the new items in a single batch.

Comment: Maybe you should provide a (`Shared`) method that returns a `List(Of String)` and assign that to the variable. Then your old list is gone and the new list takes up it's place.

Comment: Makes sense JmCilHinney, looks like the best solution so far...

Comment: Hey jmcilhinney why didn't you post an answer? Now I cannot reward you the points...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the reference for Me. Instead of creating a new list, just clear the one you have.

```
       Public Sub ReduceValueCollection(Steps As Integer)
            me.Clear()
            me.Add(First.Value)
       End Sub
```